# How to effectively manage a site with Drush make?

Tags: drush

What things are important to consider when managing a site using [Drush make](http://drupal.org/project/drush)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

"Make files", in the Drush and Drupal context, define a set of modules, themes and libraries that make up a site. While one could stick the entire sites/all/modules directory into git, the make file is a lot faster to handle, both for git and the developers. Below is a make file from an actual project of mine. I've cut out a lot as the whole file is hundreds of lines, but I've retained enough to show all of the functionality I've used.

```
; API
api = 2

; Core
core = 7.x
projects[drupal][version] = 7.14

; Contrib modules
projects[date][version] = 2.0-alpha4
projects[email][version] = 1.0

; Media and file_entity go hand in hand - please make sure they work together.
projects[media][version] = 2.0-unstable5
projects[file_entity][version] = 2.0-unstable5

; Cron modules
projects[ultimate_cron][version] = 1.6
projects[background_process][version] = 1.12

; Performance modules
projects[expire][version] = 1.0-alpha2
projects[cache_actions][version] = 2.0-alpha3

; Unstable modules
projects[menu_node_views][type] = module
projects[menu_node_views][download][type] = git
projects[menu_node_views][download][url] = http://git.drupal.org/project/menu_node_views.git
projects[menu_node_views][download][revision] = f46dd41eb8c4e693a6642a6c461afa57d99a6f1b

projects[filefield_sources_plupload][type] = module
projects[filefield_sources_plupload][download][type] = git
projects[filefield_sources_plupload][download][url] = http://git.drupal.org/project/filefield_sources_plupload.git
projects[filefield_sources_plupload][download][revision] = da374770b80fcbc0dab17158d38c8436ef29caca

projects[menu_token][type] = module
projects[menu_token][download][type] = git
projects[menu_token][download][url] = http://git.drupal.org/project/menu_token.git
projects[menu_token][download][revision] = 8c18fbb

; Libraries
libraries[mediaelement][download][type] = "file"
libraries[mediaelement][download][url] = "https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/zipball/2.7.0"

; Patches

; #1491150: node_load in menu_node_menu_link_insert is not safe - http://drupal.org/node/1491150
projects[menu_node][patch][] = http://drupal.org/files/menu_node-node_load-in-menu_node_menu_link_insert-1491150-1.patch

; Fix rendering of relation endpoints
projects[relation][patch][] = http://drupal.org/files/relation_table_endpoints_break.patch
projects[relation][patch][] = http://drupal.org/files/relation_bundle_permissions.patch

libraries[jquery-json-min][download][type] = "file"
libraries[jquery-json-min][download][url] = "http://jquery-json.googlecode.com/files/jquery.json-2.3.min.js"
libraries[jquery-json-min][download][sha1] = "2a4615b93c65dd50f92117c570121035a0327fee"
libraries[jquery-json-min][destination] = "libraries/jquery-json"
```

The api line defines which Drush make API to use for the rest of the file. One important thing to notice about the file, is that all modules either have a specific version, or point to a specific git commmit. We *never* have -dev versions in our files. When we show up at a client meeting, or hand over the make file to the [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) server, there must *never* be any surprises. The exact version included in the file should be tested and expected to pass all types of tests. This is important to be able to delivery something of high quality.

In my company, the general agreement is that every team provides a shell-script called "build", in the root of the repository, which is responsible for setting up the site, so that automated tests can be run by the same cross-team CI setup.

Module updates can be done quickly directly on sites for testing, but officially by updating the make file, and rebuilding the site.

My team currently uses this [set of build-scripts](https://github.com/letharion/Drupal-build-scripts). I'm working towards moving much of the functionality into a drush extension that will heavily use provision though. A CLI version of Aegir if you will.

Comment: Genius. Thanks for taking the time to write this up it's very helpful

Comment: Yes, I agree with Clive, upvoting as a very useful post. I'm interested in not having to repeatitively install the same set of modules and patches. @Letharion I would warmheartedly welcome if you could elaborate some day on how you proceed with that. Do you install it locally or to remote server?

Comment: @Artur, I'm not sure I follow, do you mean "enabling" modules? There are samples of automatically applying patches in the make file.

Comment: Playing around with drush make. I totally understand the reason for putting fixed version numbers in there. However, how do you update them? Is there a drush make equivalent for drush up? At some point, you need to update your versions to the newest version (especially security updates). Having to do that manually with dozens of modules seems rather tedious...

Comment: Moar questions: Do you have a .gitignore file or how do you avoid commiting "maked" files? If yes, how does that look? Tried to do something fancy with wildcard and ! but that doesn't work for directories.

Comment: I'm not aware of a "drush up" version for make files. Yes, numerous security upgrades is a bit tedious. I ignore the entire built dir, and symlink the "example.com" dir into sites/, but in other projects I've used rules like this one: `web/sites/*/files/*`, so the same should be doable for modules.

Comment: This gets my up vote but I will point out that use of patches and lack of use of -dev versions may cause many people to have variable experiences.  Typically patches are expected to be rolled from the -dev version. If you're not using a -dev version and you're failing to patch then git it a go against the -dev version. If it works, that'll be the explaination and you may need to backport it to your current stableeas of choice.

Comment: I don't really agree. Lack of -dev is what ensures consistency, not the other way around. It's each developers responsibility to ensure the patch applies, which may mean referring to a git revision instead of a stable release, but never an unpredictable -dev that can change from on build to another.

Comment: @Letharion I may ask this as a separate question, but how do you handle modules that you want available, but not enabled initially?  For example, I like having Devel available on all sites, but not always enabled.

Comment: @MPD, that shouldn't really be an issue, I pinged you in the chat about that, and maybe we can hash it out there, possibly leading to a new question later. :)

Comment: great write-up ! it would be nice to explore the rebuilding part a little further, that has always been a little bit of a mystery to me ... are you running drush make --no-core on the "living" site ?

Comment: @mojzis I believe the most common scenario is to rebuild in a new directory everytime, say, web-[timestamp], and then have your vhost dir, web, symlink to the latest web- directory when the rebuild finishes. Does that answer the question?

Comment: yes, thanks, that makes sense ... one has to realize there is no database involved in this :) so afterwards, you would just run fra and updb, right ?
 do you do this like several times a day on a dev server, too ? or do you have a "quick" workflow and a "slow" workflow from time to time ?