# File structure for custom modules in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, installation, version-control, files

I want to organize *non-core* (modules that are not bundled with core) modules in Drupal 7. This is my proposed structure:

1. Contributed modules - downloaded modules that are untouched
2. Custom modules - downloaded modules that are modified to suit the requirement
3. local modules - self-developed modules

I GUESS, the best approach for this is to make three folders within `sites/all/modules` like below:

1. `sites/all/modules/contrib`
2. `sites/all/modules/custom`
3. `sites/all/modules/local`

Now, there are two ways to install a module:

1. Manually
2. From the admin panel

While installing the new module manually, everything is fine. I can just go to the directory and place the module there.

But **how to install a newly downloaded module in `sites/all/modules/contrib` from admin-panel?

Moreover, is there any better approach for organizing non-core modules?**

Comment: I think you can not make sub folder on modules folder, that's why it will not detect the sub-folder modules. Everything should be in sites/all/modules

Comment: @bala: I disagree. I have came across many tutorials which suggest directory structure somewhat similar to what i have proposed. But the problem is that they have not mentioned any details about my doubt.

Comment: @Bala: check [this](http://tiger-fish.com/blog/drupal-7-sensible-structure-modules-folder)

Comment: Bhavik I don't know about this, thanks for sharing the link and I"m not down voted.

Comment: _downloaded modules that are modified to suit the requirement_, not recommended -> don't do it! I follow simple structure of created two directories inside the modules folder : _contrib_ and _custom_, and download the modules using drush. In this way the contributed modules automatically get placed under the contrib directory, and I do custom coding in the _custom_ directory.

Comment: @AjitS: I will think on your suggestion. But, can you please tell me how do you install module from admin-panel in contrib folder?

Comment: @BhavikShah You can't; having sub-folders under sites/all/modules is very common (I don't have a single project without that setup). So common, in fact, that if you have a /contrib folder under sites/all/modules, Drush will automatically download new projects into that folder. Installing from the admin panel is not a good idea anyway, as it screams of an insecure server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keeping your modules folder clear is important part of development. This is my common structure:

- `contrib` — modules from Drupal.org
- `custom` — modules developed for this project
- `features` — exported features for Features-driven development
- `unstable` — sandbox, forked, unstable, patched modules

Here are some examples how to organize patches/forks:

- [Drupal Boilerplate](https://github.com/Lullabot/drupal-boilerplate) from Lullabot
- [A sustainable development workflow for patching drupal](http://www.jenlampton.com/blog/sustainable-development-workflow-patching) from Jennifer Lea Lampton
- [Drush Make workflow](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33403/how-to-effectively-manage-a-site-with-drush-make/33404#33404) from @Letharion
- [Managing patches & getting your drupal patch accepted](http://drupalscout.com/knowledge-base/managing-patches-getting-your-drupal-patch-accepted) from Greg Knaddison

> But how to install a newly downloaded module in `sites/all/modules/contrib from admin-panel.

### Use [Drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush) please.

```
drush dl views rules # will download Views and Rules into sites/all/modules/contrib automatically if contrib folder exists.
```

You also can specify `--destination` where to download project.

Comment: I sometimes have a separate subdirectory sites/all/modules/git, which is either itself a symlink or which contains symlinks to external folders. This allows to have modules which have their own git history. It is particularly useful during contrib module development, where the site itself is not that important, but the modules are.

Answer (score 3):

The structure you suggest will work.

However, you should, as a general rule, not modify contributed modules that you download.  By forking a module, your local copy will be an island, and it will difficult for you to benefit from future bug fixes and other improvements added to the contributed module.

The usual way is to have *two* subdirectories below `sites/all/modules/` - `contrib` for downloaded modules and `custom` for self-developed modules.  Use *drush* instead of the admin panel to download and install in order to place downloaded modules in `contrib`.

However, sometimes you need to tweak a contributed module.

Instead of just forking a custom version, you should present your use case and requirements in the module's issue queue on Drupal.org, and upload a [patch](https://drupal.org/node/1054616) to extend the module's features to cover your use case.  By doing this, you will contribute to the Drupal community, and benefit from reviews and suggestions about your proposed patch made by other users of the module.

It may, however, take some time before your patch is incorporated in the module's official code base.  In the meantime, just keep a copy of the patch file, and use *[git](https://drupal.org/documentation/git)* to apply it to new versions of the module that are released by the module's maintainer.  If you're unlucky, you may need to reroll the patch if the module is radically changes, but this is still a better alternative than maintaining a local fork by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is the module_install module, that allows you to choose which subdirectory within /sites/all/modules to install a module to, when using the admin module installer:

https://www.drupal.org/project/module_install

Just create whichever subdirectories you want, install the module (manually put it in /sites/all/modules/contrib if you want to follow best practise!), and then enable it.