# Drush site-install and extra settings for the settings file?

Tags: drush

We are [developing a site with a make file, profile](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33403/how-to-effectively-manage-a-site-with-drush-make) and [drush-si](http://drush.ws/#site-install).
Thus far it's great, but i cant find a way how to add some slightly more complex settings to the settings.php file. For the beginning, base_url and second database would be totally enough :). Memcache and proxy are other candidates.

Or is this something that could be done in an installation profile ? Where ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the post about [Collecting and writing configuration settings to setting.php from an install profile](https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/collecting-and-writing-configuration-settings-settingphp-from-install-profile).

It describes how a custom task was injected into the installation profile and then details how [drupal_rewrite_settings()](http://api.drupal.org/drupal_rewrite_settings) was used to inject the custom settings into settings.php.

Comment: @Duncanmoo Found the article and fixed the link.